# Blazegraph error when running on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, rdf, executable-jar, blazegraph

Failed to run [Blazegraph](https://www.blazegraph.com/) (Java RDF triple store) on Windows 10 using the [simple steps](https://www.blazegraph.com/download/) from the download page.

I have a windows 10 machine with Java JDK 9 installed (See version check below). I [downloaded](https://www.blazegraph.com/download/) the latest Blazegraph executable jar and then ran "java -server -Xmx4g -jar blazegraph.jar". It reports a NullPointerException as shown below. If it is helpful the error below references [StandaloneNanoSparqlServer.java:142](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/blob/64bb8ca92eb063d45d68ec920a34b5321b80e2fe/bigdata-jar/src/main/java/com/bigdata/rdf/sail/webapp/StandaloneNanoSparqlServer.java#L142), which github shows to be `"System.setProperty("jetty.home", jettyXml.getClass().getResource("/war").toExternalForm());".`

**Commands/Response at Windows admin CMD prompt:**

```
C:\Users\aidesigner\Downloads\Blazegraph>dir
11/26/2017 09:48 PM 56,702,395 blazegraph.jar
11/26/2017 09:06 PM 0 rules.log

C:\Users\aidesigner\Downloads\Blazegraph>java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

C:\Users\aidesigner\Downloads\Blazegraph>java -server -Xmx4g -jar blazegraph.jar
INFO: com.bigdata.util.config.LogUtil: Configure: jar:file:/C:/Users/aidesigner/Downloads/Blazegraph/blazegraph.jar!/log4j.properties
WARN : SystemUtil.java:71: No CPUParser for this platform - looking for class: [org.apache.system.Windows10]

BlazeGraph(TM) Graph Engine

Flexible
Reliable
Affordable
Web-Scale Computing for the Enterprise
Copyright SYSTAP, LLC DBA Blazegraph 2006-2016. All rights reserved.
developer-pc.home
Sun Nov 26 21:08:03 CST 2017
Windows 10/10.0 amd64
amd64 Family n, Model n, Stepping n, Undeterminable #CPU=1
Oracle Corporation 9
freeMemory=521142272
buildVersion=2.1.1
gitCommit=90d9e8232969a8afdc830e856643e5416bb50d0a

// <Displays about 20 license links>

ERROR: Banner.java:160: Uncaught exception in thread
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.StandaloneNanoSparqlServer.main(StandaloneNanoSparqlServer.java:142)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you ask for support on the Blazegraph mailing list? I mean, this is pretty tool specific and I'm sure the developers might give you better answers.

Comment: By the way, an NPE looks like a bug somewhere, especially if you did everything is suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably a jre compatibility issue. I had the same problem with jre 9, switching back to jre 7 solved the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, it could be that you don't have the latest Javan running or are not in the right directory when running the code. Additionally, it is advised to be in the user account to have all necessary permission.